# Oracle 12c using jsonpath filter

Tags: json, oracle, jsonpath

I have a a json clob column **address** in my table, it looks like following:

```
{
    "BusinessObjectId":1000000246,
    "IsOrgParty":"Y",
    "IsProspectCustomer":"N",
    "PartyAccountList":
    "PartyAddressList":
        [
            {
                "@pk":663821562,
                "@type":"PartyAddress-PartyAddress",
                "AddressId":663821562,
                "AddressStatus":1,
                "AddressType":1,
                "BusinessObjectId":1000000240,
                "IsPrimaryAddress":"Y",
                "Country":"USA",
                "AddressLine1":"ADD2",
            },
            {
                "@pk":663821853,
                "@type":"PartyAddress-PartyAddress",
                "AddressId":663821853,
                "AddressStatus":1,
                "AddressType":1,
                "BusinessObjectId":1000000240,
                "IsPrimaryAddress":"N",
                "Country":"USA",
                "AddressLine1":"ADD1",
            }
        ],
```

I want to select the addressline 1 where the IsPrimaryAddress is indicated as "Y".

I used both:

```
select json_value(address,'$.PartyAddressList[?(@.IsPrimaryAddress=="Y")].AddressLine1') as address from T_Address
```

or

```
select json_value(address, '$.PartyAddressList[*]?(@.IsPrimaryAddress=="Y").AddressLine1') as address from T_Address
```

Both statements were not accepted by Oracle. Is Oracle support the filter expression for json?

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using? What do you mean by "not accepted by Oracle" ? Be specific.

Comment: Oracle 12c, it will report the grammer error

Answer (score 0):

Your's is not a valid JSON. I've corrected the json in the below demo link. have a look. something like this should work.

```
select * FROM t_address cross join
  JSON_TABLE(address,'$.PartyAddressList[*]'  
  COLUMNS ( 
            AddressLine1     VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.AddressLine1' ,
            IsPrimaryAddress VARCHAR2(5) PATH '$.IsPrimaryAddress'
          )  
         ) 
addr  WHERE to_char(IsPrimaryAddress)='Y' ;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=17e6d3e8f86db87d309d36be7b0e926d)

Comment: Thanks, is it the only way to use Json_table instead of a jsonpath filter?

Comment: @lion heart : it's the simplest available as far as I know in 12c